Ways to travel across land when there are biological landmines covering 70% of the earths surface
I am creating a post apocalyptic world where it is nearly impossible to walk anywhere habitable without being stabbed by about a dozen neurotoxic barbed tendrils that shoot from the ground, with the force of a crossbow bolt, which proceed to pull you into and under the earth.
This carnivorous subsolic organism spans nearly the entire globe, save for deserts and places that are snowy all year round. It only kills organisms larger than about a german shepherd, simply because the small animals don’t have enough mass to be worth the effort of killing.
Unfortunately, people are above the weight limit, and therefore, will be inevitably killed if they walk on my organism’s territory. This poses a problem for my characters, and I must know, how would the get from one tree-city to another?
I would prefer if they didn’t have cars, as this is set 124 years after the downfall of civilization. I was thinking stilts, but are there any other ideas?

What you are asking is plot element, it has nothing to do with the rules of your world. Off topic.

Not sure I agree that this is plot element/off-topic, the question is basically "given a certain technology level, what's the best way to move around when 70% of the earth is trying to kill you", which in theory seems to be OK to me. The tech level and capabilities of the organism need to be more clearly defined though. What reach does it have, what, if any, material is it capable of piercing, if you're on stilts why can't it grab the stilts and pull you down, etc.

Forget travel, how do people farm?

how does it detect its victims, would snowshoes work?

Detail request: What are this plant's weaknesses? We receive "how do I defeat my godlike character?" requests regularly and they always have the same answer: "you can't unless you give it an exploitable weakness." So, what're the plant's weaknesses? Note you can ask about ways to exploit defined weaknesses or you can ask for help defining weaknesses - you can't ask for both in the same question.

@user111403 I wasn't the voter, but I was sorely tempted to vote Too Story-Based. SE prohibits questions where all answers have equal value (opinion-based). So long as "you just need to write your story to accept this solution" is the only criteria for acceptance, the question should be closed. As written, this Q has that problem. My preference with new users is to help them understand the site before I start voting to close (unless it's really bad). At this time there's no way to judge a best answer (aka "story-based"). The OP needs to tell us more about the creature.

How deep do they go?

How does this "carnivorous subsolic organism" know that 70 lbs is the cutoff?  How intelligent is this organism?  Where does it come from?

You're probably thinking about this backwards. How do you want people to be able to move around? Figure that out first, then buff/nerf your toxic suction tentacles appropriately.

If they really have the strength of a crossbow bolt then stilts won't be any good, as they'll easily be shredded by them.

Overstimulation
Like any organism you want results. If tendrils shoot out without getting prey it is just wasting energy. A Venus Fly trap will stop using a 'mouth' that isn't catching anything, though first will just get less sensitive. It is a good survival strategy.
Roads can be created by simply using something to get a tendril to react and fail. Do it enough times and it will stop being used. Do repeat this once in a while to keep the road clear of new tendrils though.
A similar strategy is overstimulating on the spot. Stinging nettle has a maximum number of barbs it can fire. As a kid we sometimes raked our hands along it, too fast to be stung (most of the time) and eventually leaving a nettle, unable to sting. Short term any plant isn't really good in repeat performances, their plant biology a much slower process than our super fast and energy wasting vascular system. By overstimulating the tendril you'll get them to stop short term.
Finally there is the last, most risky option. Walk where no creatures that could trigger it have walked before. If we use stinging nettle as an example again, some doesn't (or barely) stings. Most of the time this is because they are in an area little travelled, so they do not need to waste energy on barbs, if they even produce any. Walking where nothing has walked before should be relatively safe. I wouldn't bet my life on it,though these are prime candidates to start building a road with fake signals to the tendrils.

The last suggestion opens some great narrative possibilities for high stakes travel

venus fly traps also have a recovery time, 5-7 days to reset after they trigger, so just seting it off once might clear it for days.

Hamster ball.

So long as you have a compass and a certain disdain for mortal peril, a hamster ball doesn't even have to be clear to be a usable method of travel.  A grating might be tolerable if the organism can't figure out you're distributing your weight, or if the tendrils are fairly thick, but windows of any transparent material are far preferable, and if there was a predecessor civilization it should be possible to scrounge window material.  If you have some poles inside it that you can poke out through well-sealed openings, you might even make some headway uphill, though I wouldn't recommend it for travel in the Alps.  Provided the holes are well sealed, the device is even amphibious to some degree, though one should try not to cross too near a waterfall.
On consideration, the hamster ball will double as a tiny house, meaning you want to keep bedding and other stores around.  (humans have quite limited cheek capacity...)  So there will probably be an equator of the sphere which is used for routine walking, a "bed" pole with a well-fixed mattress and secure drawers, and a "kitchen" pole set up to allow safe operation of a stove and tidy storage of its fuel.  Each of the poles will have some sort of porthole for observation in the middle with everything laid out just around it, carefully counterweighted against the opposite side.  Having fixed poles makes it possible to mount a circular rail around each one, which the traveller can grip for support to lean very far forward to try to get the ball to "roll uphill" (leading edge weighed down by the placement of weight).

How about snowshoes?
The weight-detection method of these organisms depends on a certain amount of pressure being applied to the area of ground they inhabit. If you could spread out your weight over a larger surface area, then your footsteps might not cross the pressure threshold to trigger the organism. Snowshoes are designed to do exactly this. But how big will the snowshoes need to be?
You mentioned it can be triggered by a medium sized dog, which weights around 30kg. That means each leg supports up to 15kg while walking with 2 legs on the ground at a time. That makes ~150 Newtons per leg. Assuming each paw is circular with a diameter of 6.5cm, this works out to ~45kPa of pressure needed to trigger the organism.
Your average human weighs around 60kg. Each leg must support that weight while walking, which makes for just under 600 Newtons per step. To have less than 45kPa, the snowshoes would need a surface area of ~13 square meters. Even if you elongated them into an oval shape you’re looking at 4+ meter long shoes, which would be impossible to walk in. We could reduce the snowshoe size by shuffling, thus keeping both legs on the ground at all times, but this presents problems when crossing any kind of elevation or rough terrain. Instead, you might need to crawl on all fours. If you keep 3 limbs on the ground at all times, each limb only needs a surface area of ~4.4 square meters. It’s far from ideal, but theoretically possible.
Unfortunately these calculations don’t account for the weight of any gear you’re carrying, which would be quite heavy for a long term expedition. If 60kg is the hard limit for the total weight of an explorer and their gear, exploration might only be possible for lower weight individuals such as children and short people. You can’t bring heavy clothing so you’d better pray for good weather. Expeditions would need to focus on foraging for food because you can’t carry much with you. If one of your snowshoes breaks, you’re dead because you won’t be able to afford the weight of bringing spares.
Overall this makes overland travel extremely dangerous and short ranged, but not impossible. Establishing a network of safe camps with proper structures for travellers to rest in could greatly extend the viable range of each expedition. You could build those camps in areas known to be safe from the organisms, such as on large boulders or up in the trees.
Ultimately, don’t get too caught up in the exact numbers in my answer. Choose a weight limit and snowshoe size that works best for your story.

Make them solid steel 2mm thick and about 4x square of the foot, and there you are, the stabbers can't get through. Actually solid steel heeled boots would also do, while taxing the wearer - but you want survival, not speed here.

Stilts are a similar technology.

Roads
It doesn't sound like your monster would be able to pierce through rock, so building roads from large stones should be a viable solution.

Interesting question. There are some main ideas to deal with this.
elevated transportation, air travel, armor, decoys, overloading, tracked vehicles, water. Notice those are in no order, I just randomly though of them. Like I think water is the most realistic and it's at the end.
Elevated transportation
This is only plausible for large scale projects. Think railways.
We already have many trains running on pillars that put them way above the ground. Now I'm aware that it's a post apocalyptic world. But you already have cities and people surviving. Running some trains is not an impossible task, especially small scale stuff.
Another super low tech solution is...bridges. I know it sounds absurd trying to connect cities across big distances with such measures. But if it's the only way to
move good from one place to another in safety, then it sure beats risking your life and goods going over the ground. The bridges can be made from basic or advanced materials. And if you just make it large and strong enough for a single cart that is animal pulled, then you just losing time in trips but not people.
air travel
Zeppelin time baby. Or using more boring stuff like air ships. It fits perfectly.
armor
This is tricky. But I can imagine that you can get a blacksmith to easily create a suit of steel that protected the lower half well enough. You don't need it to stop bullets, just the plant thingy. I'm aware there are challenges in that.
Mainly your legs got a lot of moving parts, and not a lot of ways to support it, for example breastplates distribute the weight. However I'm certain it is possible to create just enough flexible armor to protect your lower half.
Decoys
This largely depends on how the creature operates. But I imagine that you can simply exhaust the number of barbs it has in an area. No creature has infinite energy or the ability to keep manufacturing the barbs. Think of bolts in the zone or thumpers from Dune. All you have to do is exhaust the offensive capabilities of the organism in a limited area.
overloading and attacking
We don't know how the plants detect prey. But even in a post apocalyptic world people can experiment and figure it out. Unlike the other methods this is more of an active defense. You can smoke the area, blast large noises, set up vibration emitting devices and direct it towards the ground...etc.
This can even be a way to disable it or stun it for a while.
Also you can use literal explosives.
tracked vehicles
post apocalyptic again, I'm aware. But the thing is that people know and understand all principle of vehicles still. Like sure. Instead of millions of cars, they have like 1% of them left, fair enough. But vehicles are too damn good to simply abandon.
Tracked vehicles are not only armored to simply tank the hits, but they probably spread the weight enough that the creature won't even detect them. Also you don't even have to power them using good old oil. Electric cars or even steam engines can be used.
Water
Think Venice.
But not only in cities, oh no. Water transportation becomes way more viable and replaces land travel. Because even if the creature can detect ships, you don't need to armor it. Water will be plenty of protection on its own.
And don't just think of utilizing existing rivers. People will sure as heck dig their own canals and rivers in that situation.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I'd use a set of technologies. I think the folks who are thinking of tanks are  are on the right track, but there's a different technology that' would make sense here

 Taken from wikimedia - source here
Its simple technology, and accessible to steam era tech. And you use this to temporarily clear areas for access, beating out small patches of temporarily safe spaces. Flamethrowers optional - if you can't beat them to death, you'd still expose the plants for other means of killing them. A steamroller might work too, maybe a steam powered heated rotoflail. These could be adapted from pre-apocalypse tech and be janky
I'm assuming they would grow back though. If you can clear a path long enough, you can set up a system of what would be essentially telephone poles above the ground. Have two platforms on each at roughly standard height and put ziplines between platforms.
Of course these need maintance but it would be cool and relatively lowtech. I mean you could build bridges but that's boring

Is the mega plant sentient? Or does it detect its prey by vibration? If sentient, your people are hosed because it’ll plot a way around whatever. But if not then I suggest thumpers as in Dune — bits of sturdy metal machinery that humans roll ahead of them that go thunk. The device gets harmlessly stabbed regularly and the plant has to recover before firing again. Something like this childrens toy:


The tendrils don't just stab, they grab and pull you under the earth. Depending on how they work, you might lose your thumper to the first attack.

@user111403 You have a point, but most plants that grab latch on with organic secretions that won't stick to metal. It'll depend a lot on how the plant works. If Merpamerp updates the question with more details, I'll consider extending the answer.

Add a lawnmower blade to cut off the tendrils, and you've made the ground safer for a much longer period!

Tethered hot air balloons
The technology required to make hot air balloons is not particularly advanced. So, enterprising individuals could hop onto a balloon when the wind is blowing the right way and then let it blow towards an infestation-free (rocks? Water?) area while laying out the equivalent of a gunline. Once it reaches its destination, it drops a tower, which connects to the gunline. And then this crew operates a crank to pull the gunline, which in turn pulls the main line with blocks and whatever is needed. After that is setup, a crank crew in either end can move a balloon tethered to this main line between the two towers (one at each end). It would make sense to have a crew on each end to maintain it (and the baloons) and provide source of hot air for the balloons.
Having the balloons would avoid the problem of the line slacking so much with weight it would be really close to the ground.
With time, the best routes would be upgraded with better/taller towers, resting areas, and larger capacity balloons.
Assumptions

The landmines would not attach themselves to the lines
There are areas without infestation and there is some way to identify them at a distance, even if it is just "rocks == no mines." I assume the seasoned first/exploration crews would have ways to sound/test an area before landing, like dropping an animal and see what happens to it.


Fire. Plants do not like fire, insofar as they "like" anything, but your plant seems to have some awareness of the surroundings. Distribute some straw ahead of you, pour gasoline if your technology level is high enough, alcohol if it is lower, vegetable oil if you lost even the distillation, add some chopped wood and set it on fire, while thumping rocks to lure the plant upwards. When it cools down enough and before the plant retakes the ground, move forward, rinse & repeat.

Pedal a cart
The barbs only have the force of crossbow bolts, so thick boards forming the floor of the cart would stop them. The cart can't be pulled by a walking animal, so you would have to move it in other ways, such as pedals.
This assumes that there aren't so many land mines that the force of impacts would break apart the floor of the cart or the wheels before you get to your destination. If there are that many mines, the cart would have to be made of metal.

Surprised no one so far really mentioned any kind of chemical or biological agents.
People could use xyz chemical to temporarily or permanently disable the bio-mine organisms, or just temporarily or permanently disable their ability to sense prey so e.g. you use insect spray or you spread some grasshopper legs or pine seeds or whatever else and for the next half hour the organism is unable to do much than try to metabolize that and can't move or its way of sensing pray will not trigger for any reason until the substance is washed or rubbed off from the organism moving or whatever else.
As a result you can use whatever you want as vehicle as long as it's equipped with a way to spread the substance reliably to avoid triggering the bio-mine organisms. Usually while moving but potentially  also while standing still if it only temporarily disables the organisms.
Likewise roads could be built if there is a substance to kill the organisms and prevent them from easily spreading to that area again, so it only has to be reapplied periodically rather than continuously.
It could e.g. be a substance produced in tree cities or it has to be mined in territory surrounded by those organism so if for some reason mining and production is interrupted for too long then accessing the mine to obtain more becomes a problem which could end in one or more tree cities being totally isolated until someone from another region brings enough of the substances to clear a path between the mine and the tree cities relying on it for long enough to restart the mining / production processes.
If the substance is not easy to obtain or produce it could be the most valuable resource in the world and any tree cities which can easily obtain / produce it might have very influential compared to those tree cities which can't obtain any themselves.
